# How to highlight all cells in dataframe that contains a specific object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

| Location | Country | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany | A |
| 1 | Armenia | C |
| 1 | Zimbabwe | A |
| 2 | India | B |
| 2 | Zimbabwe | C |

How do I highlight all the cells that contain 'Zimbabwe'? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pandas' [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). You can achieve the desired output by:

```
def zimbabwe_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val == "Zimbabwe" else 'black'
    return f"color: {color}"

df.style.applymap(zimbabwe_red)
```

Comment: I am actually trying to highlight the background, not the color of the text. So I am actually looking for something like highlight_null() function which can be applied an object other than NaN values.

Answer (score 1):

```
def highlight(s):

    '''
    change the background color for a particular object in red.
    '''

    return ['background-color: red' if v == 'Zimbabwe' else '' for v in s]

df.style.apply(highlight)
```